# How to classify specific data in groups with an sql query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to make a query in sql to place specific data in groups.
So I want to classify data in the next groups:

```
[1-90m²] group1
[91-140m²] group2
[141-190m²] group3
[191-300m²] group4
[300+m²] group5
```

But I only have the exact data.. `Example 87m² -->[1-90m²] 160m² --> [141-190m²]`.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: what rdbms are you using?  Is your data actually stored with the number and letter in the same column?

Comment: What is your question? How to partition data in groups or how to convert 87m² to [1-90m²] ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally known as discretization.

I'm going to assume the values are stored in an integer field without the unit text; if this assumption is wrong or the datatype is not integer you can change this:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
    id int IDENTITY,
    value int
)

INSERT INTO @test (value) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(95),
(140),
(141),
(193),
(240),
(300),
(301)

SELECT value, 
    CASE 
        WHEN value <= 90 THEN 1
        WHEN value <= 140 THEN 2
        WHEN value <= 190 THEN 3
        WHEN value <= 300 THEN 4
        ELSE 5
    END AS group
FROM @test
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming table `YourTable` has a column `woonoppervlakte` with data like `87`:

```
select  case
        when woonoppervlakte between 1 and 90 then 'group1'
        when woonoppervlakte between 91 and 140 then 'group2'
        when woonoppervlakte between 141 and 190 then 'group3'
        when woonoppervlakte between 191 and 300 then 'group4'
        when woonoppervlakte > 300 then 'group5'
        end as [Group]
,       *
from    YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my column there is just 87 and not 87m².
the name of the column with the m² values is "woonoppervlakte" and the name of the column with the groups is "group"